# Which localisation of Visusal C++ runtime 2013 to install?

Tags: windows, installation

Visual C++ 2013 seems to come in multiple "localisation flavors". I would like advice whether and how to install the US and the DE "flavors" of VC++ 2013 in parallel on a Windows 10 system which is used by a US native administrator and multiple DE only user accounts.

Specifically, my Windows 10 system has the system default localisation at EN-US, which is also the localisation chosen for the Administrators member account. Additionally there are multiple standard user accounts which are localised to DE-DE.

In the past I have installed/uninstalled multiple SW packages which pulled in arbitrary VC++ 2013 versions, so I got 4 (!) uninstall entries which (I assume) relate to EN_US and DE_DE in x86 and x64 each.
BUT NOTE that those 4 entries consist of 2 pairs where the 2 entries within each pair are indistinguishable from each other in Control Panel (they have identical text info, version no., and x86/x64 tags). Only in registry they have different UUIDs.

My specific concerns:

Can I trust WIndows update to keep all 4 versions current (i.e are the versions listed in Windows uninstall overview unimportant) ?

Is the effectively installed localisation a *forced* system choice (because EN and DE overwrite each other) or are applications able to pick the correct localisation dlls ?

If system forced - is the effective localisation dependent on the installation order ?

Should I better uninstall all 4 C++ 2013 packages and consciously install just the latest EN-US or DE-DE version (x86 and x64) ?

If I better stick to one localisation - should I prefer the EN-US or the DE-DE version (DE-DE might be the better choice if it is a superset of EN-US functionality - OTOH later an EN_US might be automatically installed on top anyway) ?

Comment: VC++ 2013 is no longer being updated.  So if you install it, you have the current version, there won't be any updates to it.  Furthermore to be my knowledge VC++ 2013 was not binary compatible with itself, so if software required a specific version, that specific version had to be installed on the system.

Comment: According to my experiments in a VM, Windows does only hold/maintain/provide *one* set of installed files for VC 2013 runtime for each Architecture (x64 and x86). It *adds* one uninstall record for each installation *attempt* though. When I double clicked the installer multiple times I got multiple identical uninstall entries in control panel. When I "uninstalled" any of the superfluous entries, Windows just removed that entry and nothing else.

Comment: @Ramhound: What you stated about Windows maintaining multiple versions of a VC runtime (in an attempt to address dll hell) I found only to be true for VC 2005 and VC 2008. VC 2010 and above behaved similar to VC 2013.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there were multiple binary versions of VC+ 2013 that were released, software that uses VC++ 2013 could target whatever version was most current when it was being written.  All this is moot anyways since VC++ 2013 is no longer being updated.

Comment: For VC 2013 different versions are not supported simultaneously. The newest files will win the installation process. During my experiments I did *not* observe older versions being restored when a newer version uninstall record (for the same major version) was triggered in Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding (and after reading this [German blog post](https://blog.atwork.at/post/Display-Language-in-Visual-Studio-2013-Preview-andern)) VS 2013 is installed in the language of the system. You can then add additional language packs. These are only language packs, not a full installation. So in the system control you will only see one VS 2013 installation. In the VS 2013 installer you will see all languages that you installed.

It does not matter in which order you install the languages. You can even install a German version and later add English and remove German.

If you want a German or English version is your decision. I prefer the English original. After getting German linker errors for the first time and scratching my head what they could mean I switched to the English version and then understood what the errors mean. German is my native language, but I really understand English compilers and linkers better than German ones.

When an update is provided it will update the complete VS with all installed language packs.

Comment: I wonder: Where are my 3 comments to this answer which I added yesterday ?

Comment: @frowningguest I don't know. The [timeline](https://superuser.com/posts/1554119/timeline) does not show that you added any comments. What did your comments say?

Comment: Thank you for making me aware how VS 2013 behaves differently as opposed to VC runtime 2013. Though VS 2013 is obsolete now, I gather. The VC runtime 2013 is a different animal, as there are still Applications around which require it to be installed.

Comment: In the meantime I found out by experiment in a VM that each localised installer installs a *full* set of locally flavoured dlls together with a set of EN dlls for general purposes - i.e. I start believing that the different *installer* flavours are just for presenting localised messages during *installation*. I'd like to be pointed to documentation in that respect though.

Answer (score 0):

The TLDR I would state as follows:

Of the newest version of any VC runtime major release grab any language-localised installer of your preference and install it. You shall be good to go, as it installs *all* language localisations (and the installation procedure's messages are probably localised due to the installer you grabbed).

Above statement is expected to be true for VC 2010 and above at the time being (May 2020).